# Magento generates duplicate urls

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect-url

I am new to Magento and I do not yet master the PHP language. (Magento ver. 1.9.4.2 I have a problem with the automatic generation of duplicate urls. I searched several forums but none of the solutions worked.

Modified robots.txt file
I emptied the table of the magento database: core_url_rewrite
...
Note that the site contains a lot of products and is translated into several languages ​​and for each language there are products that differ from other languages. for example: products in [www.example.fr](http://www.example.fr) may contain products that do not exist in [www.example.it](http://www.example.it) and vice versa.

I discovered by chance that there are urls which are automatically generated and are duplicated for example:

example1: https://www.example.fr/NomduProduit.html?utm_source=actu-biemh this duplicate link was generated automatically and he added the? utm_source = actu-biemh at the end.

example2: https://www.example.com/ProductName.html#horizontalTab2 this duplicate link was generated automatically and it added the # horizontalTab2 at the end.

example3: https://www.example.fr/catalog/product/view/id/50157/s/ProductName/ - Catalog catalog / product / view / id / 50157 / s / has been added.

I accidentally discovered about fifteen replicated and generated sites, I would like to know where I can consult these replicated URLS? Is there a specific bdd table or specific file for that?

How do I get rid of these random replications?

PS: for each language the site contains a robots.txt, here is the robots.txt from [www.example.es](http://www.example.es):

Sitemap: https://www.example.es/examplees/sitemap.xml

User-agent: *

Disallow: / *? Aff =

Disallow: / catalogsearch /

Disallow: / *? Dir =

Disallow: / *? Example_rec_

Disallow: / *? Fa =

Do not hesitate to ask me for other information if it will help you better understand my problem in order to find a solution. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Walid,**

Please do use the open source extension, that is available in Git-Hub **URL-rewrite**, that extension will help you out and can solve your problem

**Thanks**